# at now - different date

Tags: date, at

This is my current system date

```
root@48392:/home/# date
Mon Apr 25 19:08:13 CEST 2016
```

Now I set up an at job...

```
root@48392:/home/# echo "ls" | at now
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 111254 at Mon Apr 25 19:09:00 2016
```

according to **at**, job 111254 will run on

```
Thu Nov 12 19:11:00 2054
```

Comment: Do you get a sensible time if you use "now +1 minute"?

Answer (score 2):

With regards to `now` the `man at` states that:

```
 You can also give times like now + count time-units, where the  
 time-units can be minutes, hours, days, or weeks
```

Nowhere does it say it is allowed to use `at now` without such an additional count of time-units, so I am not surprised you get undefined/unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Interestingly, the date "Thu Nov 12 19:11:00 2054" cannot even be parsed or converted to Epoch time. It would have been interesting to find out which weird arithmetic error produced this date from the current system date.

Comment: The definitive TIMESPEC `yacc` grammar does permit "now". Contrary to the man page it is acceptable without any subsequent token. (However I've not had time to check what "now" actually means.)

Comment: On my system `at now` does what you might expect, and runs the job immediately (subject to queue limits).

Comment: "Weird arithmetic error" ?? The job number is 11 12 54 and the date is Nov 12 2054. Coincidence?

Answer (score 1):

It appears `at now` is setting the time as far in the future as possible when parsing of the time string `now` fails.  The command `batch` is intended to run now, or at least as close to now as load permits.

You may be able to reschedule by using `atq` to cat the job to an `at` request with the desired time.  The man page for `at`, `batch` and related commands should give you more information

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is: `echo 'ls' | at now + 0 minutes`

This will execute the script "now".