# How to force execution of "at" job

Tags: linux, ubuntu, at

I'm using the `at` command to schedule a "update process" who cannot  be launched from my service to prevent the association of the service process with my update process, because my update process will stop and start my service a cople of times and if this child process (update process) is launched from the service and the service is stopped the child process will be stopped (killed) too (and I cannot set the `KillMode=process` in the service unit definition).

So now, I need to force the execution of a job scheduled via `at`, is this possible?

I have scheduled a job with this command:

```bsh
at now + 2 minute -M -f /path/to/my/script.sh
```

And now I want to force it to run "now", instead of waiting for that "2 minutes".

I also tried to schedule it with `at now -M -f /path/to/my/script.sh` but it doesn't starts/schedule the command.

Comment: Just do `./path/to/my/script.sh` :-P You will need to delete the `at` with `atrm` if you do not want it to run in 2 minutes.

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/279049/330217 Use `batch` instead of `at`. This will run your command in the background as soon as the system load permits it.

Comment: The -F option is (hopefully) a typo. At creates a script from your input. A plain command goes directly into the at file. There is an important difference with -f: the complete script file is copied into your at job. That means your shebang is not the first line, so it is just a comment. You may not be running the shell you expected. Also, remove the -M and it will send you mail with any error messages.

Comment: @Bodo but, with the `batch` there is no guarantee that my script will run early as possible. It's depends on the system load, right?

Comment: @Bodo Can I use this to schedule it and run it: `echo /path/to/script.sh | batch && atd -s` ???